# Time format and transform

Tags: php, sql, xml, time

I have an external XML that provides me this times : 34042, 32406.

34042  should be 147 minutes
32406  should be 120 minutes

Do you have any idea what type of time it is and how can I transform into minutes?

I'm parsing XML with PHP and introduce data in Sql

Comment: Perhaps try asking whoever generated the XML for you

Comment: you'd better ask the external provider... we could make wild guesses but these are not suitable for dependable programming...

Comment: The difference between those numbers is indeed 27 minutes (in seconds).  You'll have to ask the provider of the data what exactly the number represents.

Comment: @danmullen: The difference is 27 minutes and 16 seconds. How that discrepancy creeps in is unpredicatable unless we know how the data was generated.

Comment: @CodeNewbie yes, that's what I suggested.

Comment: they give me just the xml for API... they don't want to share other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some intuition and trial and error, I solved the logic behind the encrypted time. The two time values you have are in seconds, with an offset of 7 hours (probably because of time zone).

> 7 hours = 25200 seconds.

Once I subtract the offset from those values, I am left with 8842 and 7206.

Convert those into minutes and the first value becomes 147 minutes and 22 seconds, the second value becomes 120 minutes and 6 seconds. The values of 147 minutes and 120 minutes are just rounded (or floored) values of the time stamp.

Comment: good job... perfect... you're right...  you, mister, are a genius!